# java spring rabbitmq make a queue wait for another

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I have a java spring app and rabbitmq server. I have two queues. The first one check that A is in DB. The second saves A to db. I mean listeners. But, if I send many requests with the same A, the first queue listener is trying to check A in DB, even before the second listener saves it to the DB. How to sync two queues? So the first listener should know that the second has already saved this A to DB and then the first should check it in DB. So, if I send 1000 requests of A, the first listener checks A, there is no A, then sends to the second listener, it saves A, but on the second iteration the first checks A again, but the second listener may not complete it's job. And the first should wait then. How to solve it?

Comment: what if you will check the queue size before checking A in db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any solution, but was able to did it by using java sql transactions with different propagation levels.

Answer (score 2):

use threads, maybe with locks.
First thread deques element from Queue A, and passes it to other thread, which locks your DB, checks if A is in DB, if not - writes it to DB, unlocks DB, and accepts next passed element. Same with Queue B.
Just lock the DB before checking and writing to it, and unlock after writing to it.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this approach does not work for me - I have 5 virtual servers, each of them is running my java app with rabbit consumers, so threads solution will now work - we don't know which node is processing the request right now. I thought that I can do sth with rabbit only. But seems it's impossible